# What is the best way to calculate an element's angle when multiple rotates are applied to it

Tags: css, 3d

If you do a rotateX(180deg) rotateY(180deg) it's upside down now. So if the mouse is set to move a child element up on drag that child element will now be moving down (depending on how you have things set up).

```
-webkit-transform: rotateX(?deg) rotateY(?deg) rotateZ(?deg); // where does it point?
```

[image]

**ONLY SETUP FOR WEBKIT**

Take a look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XC7UG/2/) (code is a mess, stripped down). Draw 360 tic marks, arranged in a circle, on your computer monitor. How can you tell what tic mark the arrow is pointing to (assuming the box is at the exact center of the circle)?

A tutorial that covers the basics is [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/01/06/adventures-in-the-third-dimension-css-3-d-transforms/), [here](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/3d-transforms/).

*edit - the transform-origin being used is at the center of the cube

Comment: @Asad The question is, based on the 3 rotation values, how to calculate the direction of the arrow.

Comment: Your demo appears to be broken. When I set all sliders to their initial (left-most) positions, the box is not in its initial position.

Comment: Is suppose you'll have to project the arrow onto the x-y plane. Need to go over my linear algebra book.

Comment: sry, the sliders don't go all the way down to zero. its a jquery ui thing. if you click the space behind the box it will reload.

Comment: @user1873073 But that means that the rotation values aren't accurate, doesn't it?

Comment: Btw, why not use `<input type=range>` instead of your custom sliders? You're doing rotation which only works in cutting edge browsers, anyway.

Comment: **Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/anTTE/2/ (I use `<input type=range>`, and my sliders are accurate.)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Your example is slightly different, but it brings up an important issue. Aside from the rotations, there is also an additional translation being applied to the arrow in the OP's example. The vector in the original fiddle doesn't pass through the origin.

Comment: @Asad I see. That translation doesn't change the direction of the arrow, though, so the angle is the same in both demos. Btw, the max value in my demo should be 360, not 255 (I was thinking RGB). **Proper demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/anTTE/3/

Comment: @ŠimeVidas At non-zero rotations, it does however change what tick mark is being pointed at, since the arrow is offset from the origin by a non zero amount.

Comment: @Asad Translations don't change the angle, afaik, so the arrow should be pointing at the same angle for the same rotation values in both demos, I think.

Comment: @Asad Ah, I see what you mean. The angle is the same, but the tick marks didn't translate as well, so the arrow points at a different tick mark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** Everything that follows assumes you are using a vector that passes through the origin, as in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/XC7UG/4/). In your original example the vector is additionally offset from the origin by the vector `[0, 0, 60]`. This complicates calculations slightly, so I have used the simplified version in my explanation.

Your vector is currently defined by <strike>spherical coordinates</strike> <strike>Euler angles</strike> **consecutively applied rotations to a predefined vector**. Here is how you can use your rotations to determine the cartesian coordinates of the final vector:

1. Let us say your vector is `[0, 1, 0]` (assuming the arrow is 1 unit long and starts at the origin)
2. Apply x, y and z rotations by multiplying your vector by the rotation matrices [described here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations) in any order, replacing θ with the corresponding angle in each case:

   [image]
3. The resulting vector is your original vector transformed by the specified x, y and z rotations

Once you have obtained the rotated vector, finding the projection of the vector on the x-y plane becomes easy.

For example, considering the vector `[10, 20, 30]` (cartesian coordinates), the projection on the x-y plane is the vector `[10, 20, 0]`. The angle of this vector from the horizontal can be calculated as:

> tan<sup>-1</sup>(20/10) = 1.107 rad (counter clockwise from the positive x axis)
>
> = 63.43 deg (counter clockwise from the positive x axis)

This means the arrow points between the 63rd and 64th "tick marks" counting counter clockwise from the one pointing directly to the right.

Comment: So, you're saying that one of those three rotation values it irrelevant?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas No, all three are necessary to convert to cartesian coordinates. Once you have converted, the z-ordinal is unnecessary (since it is orthogonal to the plane we want the angle in).

Comment: How does one convert polar coordinates to Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I'm going over that bit now, I'll add it to the answer. In 2D you just go `x=r*cos(theta)`, `y=r*sin(theta)` where `theta` is the rotation about the Z axis and `r` is the length of the vector. Also, I goofed on the terminology a little, in 3D you call them spherical coordinates, not polar coordinates.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Updated the answer. Do you know if it is possible to include math markup in SO?

Comment: See on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/adding-support-for-math-notation