# How do you calculate what side of the screen a div is pointing to when 3D transforms are used?

Tags: math, css-transforms

I have asked this [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881777/what-is-the-best-way-to-calculate-an-elements-angle-when-multiple-rotates-are-a) but my math is so bad I still don't understand. I need to know what side of the screen* (top, left, bottom, right) the arrow is pointing to so I can handle dragging activity inside the divs.

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XC7UG/2/) (code is a mess and it only works in safari/chrome) illustrates the problem. To be clear, the calculation for where the arrow points should come from the exact center of the cube, not the arrow itself. If you can offer some clues about the math I'll do the work and post it here.

*"Side of the screen" means, what angle it is or what hour it would be pointing to if the screen is a clock.

```
transform: rotateX(ndeg) rotateY(ndeg) rotateZ(ndeg);
```

[image]

In this example, the arrow is pointing between 4 o'clock and 5 o'clock.

Comment: It would help if you include example input and output to clarify your question.  I added the last sentence in the hope that would clarify things some more.  If I'm wrong, though, let me know.

Comment: thanks. here is a more complicated version of the same problem if interested. the idea is to make a plugin and web page similiar to the ultimate gradient generator. http://jsfiddle.net/AWmvE/